# jQuery Tokeninput pluggin PHP no results from json

Tags: php, jquery, json, plugins

I try to use the JQuery Tokeninput. While I introduce on the search fields the text , it doesn't show anything. It stays on searching forever...

From the documentation I see that the format of the resunt of json_encode should looks like :

```
[{"id":"856","name":"House"},
{"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
...]
```

but when I access my json localhost/json.php?q=house returns datas like :

```
["house1","house2" ...]
```

so it doesn't contains the "{}" .

I'm sure that the paths to the js,and css are ok. the script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#textarea").tokenInput('link/json.php');
                    });
                </script>
```

The json code looks like :

```
$rows = array();
$q=$_GET['q']; 

$query_get_element = "SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%".$q."%'";
$query_get_element = mysql_query($query_get_element);
$row_cen = mysql_fetch_array($query_get_element);

$json=array();

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_get_element))
    array_push($json, $row2['column']);

echo json_encode($json);
```

While I search the console shows localhost/json.php?q=house 
Any advice to solve this ? Thanks in advance!

on console (google chrome I see:

```
GET http://localhost/json.php?q=house 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: so..post json.php code will be better

Comment: i just did it  now :)

Comment: array_push($json, array($row2['column']));

Comment: I receive the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was in my JSON .
It was : `array_push($json, array($row2['column']));`
 the pluggin search for the name of column and the array of column so it need to be like :

`array_push($json, array("column" => $row2['column']));`